# How do I split a dataset into training, test, and cross validation sets?

Tags: numpy, partitioning, cross-validation, indices, numpy-ndarray

First I normalized numerical data from a 1000x20 array and then created another array containing the random permutation of the row indices of the normalized data. How do I split this new array into a training, cross validation, and test set?

```
    In[150]:
    row_indices = np.random.permutation(X_norm.shape[0])

    In[151]:  
    # Create a Training Set - 60 percent of data - 600x20
    X_train = 

    # Create a Cross Validation Set - 20 percent - 200x20
    X_crossVal = 

    # Create a Test Set - 20 percent - 200x20
    X_test = 

    # If you performed the above calculations correctly, then X_train 
    # should have 600 rows and 20 columns, X_crossVal should have 200 rows 
    # and 20 columns, and X_test should have 200 rows and 20 columns. You 
    # can verify this by filling the code below:

    In[152]:
    # Print the shape of X_train
    X_train.shape

    # Print the shape of X_crossVal


    # Print the shape of X_test
```

Please forgive how bad I am at stack overflow.

Comment: is this homework? you need to split shuffled indices and then use each split to select rows from `X_norm`... e.g. do `X_norm[train_indices]` after  the split

Comment: Can you use other libraries? If yes, then [scikit-learn's train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) can be very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.split` to split your data into chunks of predefined sizes:

```
X_train, X_crossVal, X_test = np.split(row_indices, [600, 800])
```

[API Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

Comment: I'm still getting (20,) instead of (600,20) when I print X_train.shape

Comment: Does `row_indices` contains the each element index of your 1000x20 array? If so, `X_train`, `X_crossVal` and `X_test` actually contains the index of the array (not the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
X_train = X_norm[row_indices[0:600]]
```

## Create a Cross Validation Set

```
X_crossVal = X_norm[row_indices[600:800]]
```

## Create a Test Set

```
X_test = X_norm[row_indices[800:1000]]
```

also make sure when you print them that you use:

```
print(X_train.shape)
```